# NFS server refusing hostname that is allowed

Tags: nfs, ubuntu-12.04

I can't get a client to mount an NFS share that is being exported using a wildcard domain name.

Setup:
The NFS server is running DNSMasq for DHCP and DNS.

the NFS export file has

```
/export *.domain.com(rw)
```

the /etc/hosts on the NFS server (which is used by dnsmasq) has:

```
192.168.0.5 phobos
```

If I try to mount the export from phobos the server denies the request.

but nslookup on the NFS server:

```
>nslookup 192.168.0.5
5.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa    name = phobos.domain.com.
```

if I change the /etc/hosts too:

```
192.168.0.5 phobos phobos.domain.com
```

it works, but I feel like I shouldn't have to do this?  Is the NFS server not using DNS?

Comment: What's the output of `getent hosts 192.168.0.5`?

Comment: @mgorven Thanks, I think I know what you might be getting at.  The /etc/hosts file was shorting DNS lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by switching my /etc/nssswitch.conf:

```
hosts: dns files
```

from

```
hosts: files dns
```

Comment: You don't really want to do that, it's generally expected that `/etc/hosts` overrides DNS.

Comment: i suppose the other options is to move the list of hosts that dnsmasq uses to a file other than /etc/hosts?  Seems like more work.

Comment: Yup, that's probably the way to go.